# Nid of 1st menu item of current node

Tags: drupal, menu

My title says what I am looking for quite specifically.

1. Menu Item A
2. Menu Item B (Node)(active node)

   1. Menu Item B.A (Node) <- need nid of this one
   2. Menu Item B.B
3. Menu Item C

If want to get the nid of menu item "B.A".
I am not interested in using any module. Have to solve this issue by code.

Thanks for help !
mogio

Answer (score 0):

In your node you will have `book` element which represents menu link.

You can do this:

```
$book_link = $node->book;
$next_link = book_next($book_link); // next item in flattened tree
$first_child_node = menu_get_object('node', 1, $next_link['link_path']);
```